# Masonry only on page return, layout overlapping

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, overlap, masonry

I'm currently having a weird bug. It only happens on Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge.

On the first page load, the layout looks good, as it needs to be. Once you go to a different page, and after you decide to return to the previous page where the Masonry is, the layout is broken, overlapped.

Demo / Codepen: `codepen.io/baidoc/pen/JbMBvX`

**and here's a video demonstration directly on IE11:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/l8eiwchb5yoiygg/bug_explained.mov?dl=0

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to use imagesloaded since not all images are loaded before masonry is being called. Add [imagesloaded](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout.html#imagesloaded) to your page and then call masonry like this:

`$('.grid').imagesLoaded( function() {
$('.grid').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
    gutter: 20,
    percentPosition: true
});
});`